# How to disable submit button when validation fails and enable it back after it passes using validation.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [validate.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) for validation in my site. so how can i disable submit button when validation fails and enable it back after it passes. i have tried it by adding following code to success callback

```
success: function(label) {
            label.html(" ").addClass("pop_valid");
            if($('#form').validate()){
                $('#submit -button').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
```

by this i am able to enable it when total form is valid but if after that some field was again changed and if form becomes invalid the how to disable it again? anyone can pls help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to disable the button

```
 $('[id$=helobtn]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

And to enable try the following:

```
$('[id$=helobtn]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

hope this will help you...........Or you can [View this link to get what you require..](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-enable-button-in-form)

**Updated** 
I think you want to do it on Change the value. if so then you have to validate on blur for textboxes and **Change** for dropdown list like following:
For text box

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=test]').live('blur', function () {
            if (validate) {
                // enable btn 
            } else {
                // disable btn 

            }

        });


         });
```

For Dropdownlist

```
 $('[id$=test]').live('change', function () {
            if (validate) {
                // enable btn 
            } else {
                // disable btn 
            }
        });
```

Comment: i know how to enable or disable a button. i want to do it when form is valid/invalid based on it enable/disable the button that too should happen without clicking submit button

Comment: And for your information i am not that noob in jquery, javascript

Comment: can't we do it using validate.js

Comment: @SatyaTeja Why you want to keep more code.... try to do custom .... Create a js file and do what ever you want that will much easier for you to edit the code.. and logic... compare to prebuilt file

Comment: i want it through validate.js because if i have some 8-9 fields then i have to write 8-9 blur or change events which will look like inefficient code

Comment: @SatyaTeja hmmm you can create common method for that toooo

Comment: actually validate.js already used in my site and i using many of its features in my code so i should do it with that only

Comment: @SatyaTeja which version you are 1.10 or 1.9??